# Can we use Vuforia with NativeActivity on Android

Tags: android, vuforia

All the samples from Vuforia official website use pure Java or Java together with c++. But, my application uses only NativeActivity, in other word, it contains no java code. The question is can I use Vuforia in an application which has only c++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeActivity is just a Java file provided by the framework: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/NativeActivity.java

Any Android app will need to handle the Android Activity Lifecycle and in your case it will need to wrap any C/C++ code you may have.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I can extend the NativeActivity class and write some functions with Java.